# Recursive cte addition in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to add the total value to the parent nodes.(totaling the total value to base to top levels). 118 records are there and 1-8 levels.

```
Root ACCCODE='00001'
Root ACCPARENTCODE='0'
```

[image]

Eg:  adding total value of `ACCCODE='00054'` -556 to `ACCCODE-'00052'` where relation is `ACCCODE=ACCPARENTCODE`.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your current code and the specific error message or problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you what the output to display this.

```
DECLARE @vtExp TABLE
(
    ACCCODE CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    ACCName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ACCParentCode CHAR(50) NULL,
    ACCExpense FLOAT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @vtExp (ACCCODE,ACCName,ACCParentCode,ACCExpense)
VALUES('00000','Account 00000',NULL,0)
    ,('00001','Account 00001','00000',0)
    ,('00046','Account 00046','00001',10)
    ,('00048','Account 00048','00001',15)
    ,('00050','Account 00050','00001',23)
    ,('00051','Account 00051','00046',13)
    ,('00052','Account 00052','00048',7)
    ,('00053','Account 00053','00048',4)
    ,('00055','Account 00055','00050',11)

;WITH cteR
AS(SELECT ACCCODE , AccName, AccParentCode,AccExpense, 0 as LVL ,CAST('00000' AS VARCHAR(500)) AS listAccParentCode
    FROM @vtExp
    WHERE ACCCODE ='00000'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT E.ACCCODE , E.ACCName , E.ACCParentCode, E.AccExpense , R.LVL + 1 , CAST(listAccParentCode + '\'+ E.ACCCODE AS VARCHAR(500))
    FROM    cteR as R
    INNER JOIN @vtExp AS E
    ON E.ACCParentCode = R.ACCCODE  
    )

SELECT R1.ACCCODE
    ,R1.ACCName
    ,R1.ACCParentCode
    ,R1.LVL
    ,(SELECT SUM(AccExpense) FROM cteR as R2 WHERE CHARINDEX (R1.AccCode ,R2.listAccParentCode ,0)> 0) AS Total_AccExprense 
FROM cteR as R1
--ORDER BY ACCCODE,lvl
--OPTION(MaxRecursion 0)
```

and the output looks like this:

```
ACCCODE ACCName ACCParentCode   LVL Total_AccExprense
00000   Account 00000   NULL    0   83
00001   Account 00001   00000   1   83
00046   Account 00046   00001   2   23
00048   Account 00048   00001   2   26
00050   Account 00050   00001   2   34
00055   Account 00055   00050   3   11
00052   Account 00052   00048   3   7
00053   Account 00053   00048   3   4
00051   Account 00051   00046   3   13
```

Comment: I invented those sample records . If you have some sample records , add then to the initial question.

Comment: Thank you very much sabin,  this is the output which I want.. God bless you